# Is it possible to move a part of a row of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to move down a row of a table one position down except for one column. My table is something like this:


1 | a | aa 
2 | b | bb 
3 | c | cc 

And I want it to be like this:

1 | b | bb 
2 | a | aa 
3 | c | cc 

I tried to move it using moveRow() but the problem is that it moves my entire row? Does somebody know how to do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is filling the JTable? Perhaps look at it this way, for this particular example you provided, if the **first** column was editable and you change 1 to 4, then change 2 to 1, then change 4 to 2. Now do it with code.

Comment: There is no method that does this for you. You need to create your own. One way would be to save the two values in the first column. Then you invoke the moveRow() method. Then you manually invoke the setValueAt(...) method to reset the values in the first column back to the appropriate row. Or, if you are just using the first column to be a row number then maybe you can use the [Row Number Table](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) approach. The row number is not part of the model so you just move the row normally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, one approach would be to define a `javax.swing.table.TableModel` that returns the row index for the first column, and fields from row records for the other columns. Then, **moving part of the row in the table just means moving a full row in the underlying data model**.

```
  class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
      //...
      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
          Object value;
          switch( col ) {
              case 0: value = (1+col);
              // other cases are fields from rows.
          }
      }
```

Other options include:

- Moving rows, then moving some fields back.
- Representing the table data model as a two-dimensional array, and moving only desired cells.